# Powershell pipeline Invoke-Sqlcmd won't work in SQL agent, how to fix?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm typing to implement a Powershell script (that works in Powershell) in the SQL server agent. In this script, I fetch the SQL server version (among others) of all the registered servers (+/-100) on the management server and save the result in a table in a specific database on the management server. If I execute the script from Powershelll or Powershell ISE, this works like a charm; the destination table is filled with the correct data.
However, if the script is placed in a job in SQL server and executed, the output is NULL.

What have I tried:

- iterate over the servers by a "foreach" statemement and execute a query per server, saving the outcome in a pipeline. (this is the one that works in powershell but fails to yield the data in SQL agent.)
- Implement the query-execution and saving of the data in a "get-childitem"- pipeline, by addition of the "Invoke-Sqlcmd" and "Write-SqlTableData" statements in the pipeline. Couldn't get this to work, the message "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input" is returned.

According to the documentation of Invoke-Sqlcmd however, the parameter "-ServerInstance" is the only parameter that accepts pipeline values. And that is the only one I used (for iterating over the servers); the other parameters are the same for each iteration.

- changed the module from "sqlserver"to "dbatools": same outcome.
- execute the ps1-script in management studio (xp_cmdshell 'PowerShell -noprofile "[path/filename]"'). Doesn't work.

Any ideas, how can I fix this?

```sh
Powershell-script that works in Powershell:

 $CreateTable = 
     "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects where name='SQL_server_current_versions' and xtype='U')
     DROP TABLE [SQL_server_current_versions];
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SQL_server_current_versions](
     [Machine_name] [varchar](20) NULL,
     [SQL_Service_name] [varchar](20) NULL,
     [Instance_name] [varchar](30) NULL,
     [VersionBuild] [varchar](20) NULL,
     [Current_SP] [varchar](10) NULL,
     [Edition_32_or_64_bit] [varchar](40) NULL,
     [IsWindowsAuthOnly] [bit] NULL,
     [IsClustered] [bit] NULL
     )"
 SQLserver\Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance RIVM-MANDB-W01P -Database SSCC_db -Query $CreateTable
    
 $query = 
         "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS [MACHINE NAME],
         SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS [SQL SERVICE NAME],
         SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS [INSTANCE NAME],
         SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [VersionBuild],
         SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS [Current SP],
         SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS [Edition 32 or 64 BIT],
         SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly') AS [IsWindowsAuthOnly],
         SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS [IsClustered]"
    
 foreach ($server in (Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -is [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServer]} | select ServerName))
     {$server.ServerName
         if ($server.ServerName -ne "RIVM-MANDB-W01P\SSRS")
         {SQLserver\Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server.ServerName -Database master -Query $query -OutputAs DataTables | SQLserver\Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance RIVM-MANDB-W01P -DatabaseName SSCC_db -SchemaName dbo -TableName SQL_server_current_versions}
     }
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The version that SQL Agent uses, under SQLPS, can be *several* versions behind the host OSes; which can lead to (significant) differences in behaviour or lack of support for functionality.

Comment: SQL Server version 14

Comment: OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a SQL Server 2017 host to check what version of Powershell SQLPS uses on that one, and I can't find a table. Though as Powershell 5 came out in Feb 2016 I wouldn't be half surprised if the SQLPS shipped with 2017 uses Powershell 4. If you connect to the host running SQL Server you could find out by running `sqlps` and then `$PSVersionTable` in a Powershell window. It's it's running something like 3.0 then that may well be your problem.

Comment: As well as the output of `$PSVersionTable` please also include the output of `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`. PowerShell has seperate module installations for 32-bit and 64-bit processes, so what works in a 32-bit PowerShell ISE may not work in a 64-bit SQL Agent job and vice-versa.

Comment: PSVersion: 5.1.14393.4583 and 
[Environment]::Is64BitProcess = True

Comment: Thanks for the reactions so far! What I was wondering: how is powershell executed from within windows any different from the powershell run from the SQL server agent?